# how to allocate dynamic static multi dimensional array

Tags: c, memory-management

How can I make a memory allocation to the following multi dimensional array?

```
char* array[NMAX];
```

Comment: The answer to this question is in link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641476/using-dynamic-memory-allocation-for-arrays]

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NMAX 50
char* array[NMAX];
```

is an array of 50 character pointers.

You have to loop trough all of them and allocate memory for each one.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < NMAX ; i++ )
{
    array[ i ] = malloc( sizeof( char ) * 80 ) ;
}
```